# Silverlight, EF, member collection of type EntityCollection - not sure how to pass via WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework

I get a security error:

> The inner exception is: {System.Security.SecurityException --->
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.

UPDATE
My problem is because Categories type (that is passed trough WCF) has inside a Products collection. The Categories and the rest of the model types are generated code with Entity Framework. The Products member in Categories is of type EntityCollection.

The Products collection in class Categories: (generated code)

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("inventory_db_bigModel", "Products_fk", "Products")]
    public EntityCollection<Products> Products
```

The question is how do I declare the Products collection in the client ServiceReference ?
I tried with ObservableCollection and Generic List but it gives me the same Security Error.
The client ServiceReference code is generated code and I'm not sure how the solution is so that I do not have to edit it each time it's regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` and/or `crossdomain.xml` on the WCF service?

By design Silverlight is barred from making cross domain calls to prevent security threats like *cross-site forgery*.

> To enable a Silverlight control to access a service in another domain, the service must explicitly opt-in to allow cross-domain access. By opting-in, a service states that the operations it exposes can safely be invoked by a Silverlight control, without potentially damaging consequences to the data that the service stores.

To allow the connection you have to set up either a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of the service you wish to consume.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has more information.

Comment: Yes I have those files. Another part of the application wich retrieves a list of Users with GetUsers works fine, so the communication with the WCF Service doesn't have problems. This Users model type doesn't have Entity Framework Collections inside it. The Categories model type has a Entity Framework Collection type inside it as I explained in the post update. So the error I get is because of this entity collection that's inside, and I am not sure how to pass it with wcf.

Comment: @PaulRusu - why didn't you include that information in your question? It changes the nature of the problem completely.